# Using dynamically generated pages in Rainmeter Webparser

Tags: rainmeter

I am trying to make a Rainmeter plugin to download the daily image from http://miniature-calendar.com/

When I give the daily site statically, it downloads and displays the image, however if I try to get the daily site by using variables, it fails and does not download anymore.

The code I am using now:

```
[Rainmeter]
Update=1000

[MyMeter1]
Measure=Time
Format=%y%m%d

[MeasureImage]
Measure=Plugin
Plugin=Plugins\WebParser.dll
UpdateRate=120000
MeasureName=MyMeter1
DynamicVariables=1
Url=http://miniature-calendar.com/%1/
RegExp=(?siU)<div class="post-body">\s*<p><img src="(.*)" alt="" title="(.*)"
StringIndex=1
Download=1
DownloadFile=daily.jpg
```

This way the About tab says that WebParser has an empty Url and does not download the image. However if I say `Url=http://miniature-calendar.com/160113/` then it downloads the appropriate image.

What should I change to make it working?

Comment: The `WebParser` plugin does not have a field `MeasureName` where you can use that `%1` information. Put that into a `String` measure and let it return the whole URL or use dynamic variables as `Url=http://miniature-calendar.com/[MyMeter1]/`